# What is the response from google calendar api channels?

Tags: django, google-calendar-api

I am trying to sync my django server with Google Calendar API, and I want to add an event in the calendar and receive it in my django server.

My server looks like that:

the code where i get my google credentials, according to my calendar, and **create a channel** that will access my endpoint

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(user_credentials, SCOPES)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# Defina a URL do webhook
webhook_url = 'https://myserver.com/webhook/'

# Defina os parâmetros da solicitação de watch
watch_request = {
    'id': str(uuid.uuid4()),
    'type': 'web_hook',
    'address': webhook_url
}

# Registre o webhook para o calendário do usuário
try:
    calendar_id = 'primary'  # ID do calendário do usuário
    watch_response = service.events().watch(calendarId=calendar_id, body=watch_request).execute()
    print(f'Webhook registrado com sucesso: {watch_response}')
except HttpError as error:
    print(f'Erro ao registrar o webhook: {error}')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('webhook/', views.webhook_handler, name='webhook_handler'),
]
```

something like my **views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest, HttpResponse
import json

def webhook_handler(request):
    # Verifique se a solicitação é válida
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Somente solicitações POST são aceitas')

    # Obtenha o corpo da solicitação
    print('request headers', request.headers)
    print('request type', request.content_type)
    print('request params', request.content_params)
    print('request data', request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

    # Processar as notificações recebidas
    if 'channelId' in body:
        # Essa é uma solicitação de verificação de integridade do Google Calendar API
        return HttpResponse(body['challenge'])

    if 'id' in body:
        # Essa é uma notificação real sobre uma mudança no calendário do usuário
        event_id = body['id']
        # Faça algo com a notificação recebida

    # Responda com um código de status 200 para indicar que a solicitação foi processada com sucesso
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

When I add an event in my calendar or remove something, I get a request on my server with this logs:

```
request headers { 
    'Content-Length': '0', 
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 
    'Host': 'myserver.com', 
    'User-Agent': 'APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)', 
    'Accept': '*/*', 
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 
    'X-Forwarded-For': '66.102.6.212', 
    'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https', 
    'X-Goog-Channel-Expiration': 'Fri, 21 Apr 2023 17:40:11 GMT', 
    'X-Goog-Channel-Id': '0834309284029384092309', 
    'X-Goog-Message-Number': '2001969', 
    'X-Goog-Resource-Id': 'aosidjasoi1jasdj10093809df', 
    'X-Goog-Resource-State': 'exists', 
    'X-Goog-Resource-Uri': 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json' 
}
request type text/plain
request params {}
request data
```

With nothing in the body, or params, 0 length and request.headers have informations that i previously had. What am i missing?